# ASP.NET - Tab order not working after ajax postback - Goes to the browser url

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have used Update Panels in my ASP.net webpage. I have a modal popup. But the tab index is set to -1 for all the parent page controls once the modal popup comes in picture.

Does anybody has resolution for this. I tried again reseting the tab index through javascript......But its not working(may be DOM is not getting refreshed)

Regards,
Justin Samuel

Comment: Is tabs and modal popup AJAX control toolkit controls?  Or something else?

Comment: Yes they are AjAx toolkit controls.

Comment: Also I was going through this http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax  which states that its like disadv that comes with updatepanels.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen when you have multiple ModalPopupExtender controls open at the same time.  If you hide whichever popups you aren't currently using, that fixes the problem.  (Or at least it did in my case.)